# How to localize enum values in GWT client code?

Tags: java, gwt

I am using an enumeration class in my GWT client's code to define a set of types.

```
public enum MyType {

    FIRST_TYPE("first"), SECOND_TYPE("second"), THIRD_TYPE("third");

    private String title;

    private MyType(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

}
```

How is it possible to localize the enum values to translate them into different languages? The `title` field is not that important and could be dropped if this helps to solve the problem.

I know the `ResourceBundle` approach from Java, but that is not working in GWT's client code.

Comment: Could you explain why RB is not working with gwt?

Comment: `java.util.ResourceBundle` is not available to client side GWT code. If trying to use it you get an "No source code is available for type java.util.ResourceBundle;..." error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using GWT's `ConstantsWithLookup` interface.
Here is the solution:

*MyType.java*

```
public enum MyType {

    FIRST_TYPE, SECOND_TYPE, THIRD_TYPE;

    private final MyConstantsWithLookup constants = GWT.create(MyConstantsWithLookup.class)

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.constants.getString(this.name());
    }
}
```

*MyConstantsWithLookup.java*

```
public interface MyConstantsWithLookup extends ConstantsWithLookup {

    String FIRST_TYPE();

    String SECOND_TYPE();

    String THIRD_TYPE();
}
```

*MyConstantsWithLookup.properties*

```
FIRST_TYPE = first
SECOND_TYPE = second
THIRD_TYPE = third
```

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add to @thommyslaw answer that in some cases you may need to pass Enums thru the wire. I mean make them serializable.
In such cases putting GWT.create() inside the Enum will not work.
Here is where some kind of Singleton Glossary class will be handy, like:

```
public class LEGlossary {

private static LEGlossary instance=null;
private static final LocalizationEnum localConstants=GWT.create(LocalizationEnum.class);

private LEGlossary(){

}

public static LEGlossary instance(){
    if(instance==null){
        instance=new LEGlossary();
    }
    return instance;
}

public String localizedValue(Enum<?> value){
    return localConstants.getString(value.name());
}


}
```

Where **LocalizationEnum** in my case extends **ConstantsWithLookup** interface.
In this way you isolate the localization code on the client and leave the Enum free to pass thru the wire.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you, since it seems to be the gwt way [Internationalization](http://www.projectpossibility.org/projects/word_prediction/gwt-linux-1.4.60/doc/html/com.google.gwt.doc.DeveloperGuide.Internationalization.StaticStringInternationalization.html)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I already use `Constants` and `Messages` interfaces but never came in touch with `ConstantsWithLookup` interface.