# How to internationalize error messages when using Hibernate Validator with GWT?

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, internationalization, hibernate-validator

I'm looking for a bit of help on how to internationalize my hibernate validation messages while using GWT, so that it works with both client and server messages.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261858/internationalization-in-hibernate-validators), I should put a ValidationMessages.properties file in my class path, or use the following code:

```
Validation
    .byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
    .configure()
    .messageInterpolator(
        new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(
            new PlatformResourceBundleLocator("com.mycompany.Messages")))
    .buildValidatorFactory()
    .getValidator();`
```

But will this method work on the client side, with GWT code? What should I do to make it work on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

Please check [GWT Internationalize](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/i18n.html).

If you want to internationlize for messages with GWT , check [Static String Internationalization](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html) and [Dynamic String Internationalization](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuideDynamicStringInternationalization).
I used [GWT ConstantsWithLookup](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/ConstantsWithLookup.html) for constant datas (such as Text of Buttons , Text ofLabels  ). 

And I use [GWT Messages](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Messages.html) for my message datas (such as alerts , warning , confirm , prompt dialogs).

Don't be forget to add configuration at gwt.xml file as below...

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="en"/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="ja"/>
<!-- set the fallback for locale default Japan  -->
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="ja"/>
........
```

I used Local **en** for English and **ja** for Japanese. I created ListBox for user to choose Locale  as they prefer and used [Cookie](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Cookies.html) to maintain as user perference. Below is my sample codes for saving locale in cookie to internationalize at next-time open...

```
    public static void initializeLocaleBox(final ListBox localeBox) {
    String currentLocale = LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName();
    if (currentLocale.equals("default")) {
        currentLocale = "ja";
    }
    String[] localeNames = LocaleInfo.getAvailableLocaleNames();
    for (String localeName : localeNames) {
        if (!localeName.equals("default")) {
            String nativeName = LocaleInfo.getLocaleNativeDisplayName(localeName);
            localeBox.addItem(nativeName, localeName);
            if (localeName.equals(currentLocale)) {
                localeBox.setSelectedIndex(localeBox.getItemCount() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    localeBox.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
        public void onChange(final ChangeEvent event) {
            String localeName = localeBox.getValue(localeBox.getSelectedIndex());

            Date now = new Date();
            long sevenDays = now.getTime();
            // seven days
            sevenDays = sevenDays + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
            now.setTime(sevenDays);
            Cookies.setCookie("locale", localeName, now);
            UrlBuilder builder = Location.createUrlBuilder().setParameter("locale", localeName);
            Window.Location.replace(builder.buildString());
        }
    });
}

public static boolean isLocaleJapan() {
    String currentLocale = LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName();
    return currentLocale != null && currentLocale.equals("ja") ? true : false;
}

public static boolean isLocaleEnglish() {
    String currentLocale = LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName();
    return currentLocale != null && currentLocale.equals("en") ? true : false;
}
```

For changing **URL** to localize , I converted with GWT as follow..

```
public static final String getBaseUrl(final int codesvrPort) {
    String locale = Cookies.getCookie("locale");
    if (locale == null || locale.equals("")) {
        locale = "en";
    }
    String baseUrl = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + GWT.getModuleName() + ".html";
    if (GWT.getHostPageBaseURL().contains("localhost")
            || GWT.getHostPageBaseURL().contains("127.0.0.1")) {
        return baseUrl + "?locale=" + locale + "&gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:" + codesvrPort;
    }
    return "";
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757608/how-to-localize-enum-values-in-gwt-client-code) is useful link for you.  I am sorry for too many links. Have some useful for you :)

### **Edit(Suffixing a properties file)**

Qouted from [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/i18n.html) link.

> ***Note: Suffixing a properties file***
>   If you've never dealt with internationalization before, you may be wondering why the _de suffix is appended to German properties file. The suffix _de is the standard language tag for the German language (Deutsch). Languages tags are abbreviations that indicate a document or application's locale. In addition to specifying the language, they can also contain a subtag indicating the region of a locale. For example, the language tag for French-speaking Canada is fr_CA.
>   
> In GWT, properties files indicate the locale with a language code suffix (just like Java resource bundles). The exception is the properties file for the default locale. When no locale is explicitly set at runtime, the properties file with no language code suffix is used. For StockWatcher, you've specified the default translation with annotations instead of using a default properties file.

Comment: so the only way to change the locale, is to specify the locale in the url with the `locale=xx` argument?

Comment: Does this mean that if a user visits your page, at first everything is loaded in the default language, then you detect the locale from the cookie, and refresh the page for him with locale=xx in the url? that seems very inefficient

Comment: @ClickUpvote please check **Suffixing a properties file** section from http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/i18n.html

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question regarding the query string / refresh approach

Comment: @ClickUpvote your second comment was mean to my **getBaseUrl()** method. I used it on some page navigation , such as "_getBaseUrl(9997) + "#mylink:" +123);_". And I think , this may depends how you figure out.

Comment: @ClickUpvote I had edited my answer. pls check for naming properties files. If you still get troubles with it , pls test by yourself and then you will realize what I mean.

Comment: Actually, my problem is, lets say my default language is english, and a user specified French as his language. So I store that as a cookie. But the next time the user visits the app, it would still show everything in english first, until it detects from cookie that his lang is french, and redirects him. That doesn't seem efficient. It should load the app in french by default if there's a cookie for french.

Comment: @ClickUpvote yes , I absolutely know what you mean . :) If you show with english first , user will show english first and their prefer language is next. If you have as **Interceptors** for it , for example checking with URL mapper, you wouldn't need to show with English first. You can used it with some utilities such as Spring MVC or others... Or open another topic. My answer is for internationalization with messages or constants.

Comment: How would I set it to french by default? via the meta tag?

Comment: @ClickUpvote my above example codes set default to Japan if does no contain any **locale** in url due to "_<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="ja"/>_".French **fr** also. But pls remeber , you would have relative properties file also.

Comment: I'm asking about if the user has french selected, but my default is english, how would i change the default to be french for that user?